# Can we combine select * with dense_rank()

Tags: sql, db2

I want to fetch all the records from table along with rank.
SO is it possible to get all columns without giving the name
something like: Select *,dense_rank() over(column) from table.

Comment: please submit a [mcve] of what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
select t.*, dense_rank() over(order by column)
from table t;
```